# Failed to resolve System.Void UIKit.UITableView in Xamarin iOS

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

If I build my Visual Studio project for Xamarin.iOS with the Linker Behaviour set to "Don't Link", everything works fine except the resultant IPA file is 30MB (which expands to 101MB on the app store!).

If I change the Linker Behaviour to anything else (Link All or Link SDK) then I receive the following compile error;

```
Error   32  Failed to resolve "System.Void UIKit.UITableView::set_DataSource(UIKit.UITableViewDataSource)" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"
```

I want to use the linker so that the size of the project comes down to a respectable size. Can anyone elp with this error?

Comment: From the linker page, Xamarin would like you submit a bug report for when your app only works with Don't link http://developer.xamarin.com/Guides/ios/Advanced_Topics/Linker/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was because your older version of `sqlite` was based on an older (preview) version of the unified API.

Some API signatures changed like, in the case, to allow using protocols more easily (which means using interfaces instead of types).

Note that turning off the linker will remove the **build** failure - but that symbol is still missing and you can run into this at **runtime** (which is worse since you'll need to test carefully to ensure that does not get hit).

Comment: I mistakenly thought that if I was using an old version of sqlite then it would be listed as an update waiting. Which it didn't so I just had to go through all of them to find out which one is was. Thanks for the info as well!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the reference to sqlite and re-added it again through nuget.  This resolved the issue.